# Calculating Harmonic Numbers

Tags: harmonic-numbers

I'm hoping someone can confirm if I did this right, is the expression for calculating the nth harmonic number as written below?

$$
H_n=\gamma+\lim_{h\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(h\right)-\sum_{k=n+1}^{h}\frac{1}{k} \right)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite
$$
\gamma+\lim_{h\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(h\right)-\sum_{k=n+1}^{h}\frac{1}{k} \right)=\gamma+\lim_{h\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(h\right)-\left[\sum_{k=1}^{h}\frac{1}{k} -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\right]\right).
$$
$$
=\gamma+\lim_{h\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(h\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{h}\frac{1}{k}\right)+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\gamma-\lim_{h\to\infty}\left(\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{h}\frac{1}{k}}_{H_h}-\ln\left(h\right)\right)+H_n
$$
By definition $\gamma := \lim\limits_{h\to\infty}\left(H_h - \ln h\right)$, so we have
$$\gamma-\gamma+H_n=H_n.$$